# How to reset admin account after the person left our organization

Tags: azure-devops

Is there an easy way to change Azure DevOps Project administrator? The previous person in charge has left our company and now I'd like get the admin rights. I have control over previous admin email account, but resetting password (clicking on "Can’t access your account?") doesn't work for some reason. I'm getting "The email or username you entered does not exist. Please check that you have typed your email or username correctly".

Comment: Some clarifications to the original post. The admin email has been wiped already, so there is no email account any longer (although, I can create the same if needed). Also, Azure still mentions the previous admin's email in Settings -> Project details, but when I click on it, I get "Unknown user". Looks like Azure DevOps knows that that user has been removed already from our Microsoft 365.

Answer (score 0):

Any account which is the Organization Owner or member of Project Collection Administrators (both at the organization level) can add your account to the Team Project - Project Administrators group.

The Organization level security groups are here:

[https://dev.azure.com/[organization-name]/_settings/groups](https://dev.azure.com/%5Borganization-name%5D/_settings/groups)

Check the members of Project Collection Administrators

Wes

Answer (score 0):

> How to reset admin account after the person left our organization

**First**, even if you create the same email address to log in to Azure devops, you still cannot log in. Because each account has a unique ID corresponding to it in Azure devops, we call it `VSID`. When you create a new account, it will get a different `VSID` from the previous one. This new `VSID` does not exist in azure devops, so it will not inherit all the permissions of the previous old `VSID`. This is why you get Unknown user error.

**Second**, if you want to change Azure DevOps Project administrator, you could check if the members of PCA (Project Collection Administrators). If you have any other PCA in your organization, you could contact that user to change the Project administrator.

**Third**, if the person left your organization is the only one in your PCA, you need to check if your organization connected to the AAD, if yes, you could follow this document to change the owner of the organization, then to change the Project administrator:

[Assign a new owner to your orphaned organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/resolve-orphaned-organization?view=azure-devops)

**Latest**, if you are not satisfied with the above situation, please contact Azure DevOps Support and provide your organization and the new PCA account with additional comment in private.